# how to find transient response chracteristics of a step function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How do you plot a transient response of a function on MATLAB?

For Example, I have the function:

```
s1 = Feedback(J1,h)
```

I can get the step response by utilizing `step(s1)`

When typing `s1 = Feedback(J1,h)`
I result in the graph below:

How can I find the transient response characteristics of this a specific step function on MATLAB?

[image]

Comment: When you say the transient response, what do you mean?  Because the transient response is taken with step. The treansient response is the part from step where it is still not stable in a single value. or do you want the impulse response?

Comment: You have clarified my question Thanks!  I your case how would you find the transient response with the step, if i am able to receive the transient response graph?

Comment: could you please rephrase that question?

Comment: To find the transient response characteristics, why dont you use the transient response characteristics descriptions? Wikipedia can help you........... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_response . Remember to use google before asking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To acquire the transient response data of a system in MATLAB you can use the [`step`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/step.html) function **with output arguments**

```
>> [yout, tout] = step(syst);
```

`yout` and `tout` will be the data MATLAB uses to plot the step response of the system if you had used just

```
>> step(syst);
```

If you don't supply a time vector to [`step`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/step.html) MATLAB will automatically determine the time for which it calculates the step response of the system. This is generally *undesirable* and you should produce a time vector for MATLAB to use.

If, instead, you are interested in the transient response characteristics you can use the MATLAB function [`stepinfo`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/stepinfo.html)

```
>> stepinfo(syst)
ans = 

        RiseTime: 0.5541
    SettlingTime: 2.1165
     SettlingMin: 0.4451
     SettlingMax: 0.5454
       Overshoot: 12.7135
      Undershoot: 0
            Peak: 0.5454
        PeakTime: 1.2441
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you